# Limit Projects in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I am a user of Firebase Google today I was creating a project in the console of Firebase and the following message appeared: You're 2 projects away from the project limit. I was kind of worried about that and scheduled the deletion of several projects from Google Cloud Plataform Later I returned to the console and the projects I erased disappeared but when creating a project the message is still there. My questions are: How many projects can I have in the free Firebase plan? When deleting the project the count and restarted or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete a project, it's not fully deleted until after 30 days.  You should have received an email notification about that.  Until it's finally deleted, it will still count against your max.

The project limit might be different for each individual Google account.  In general, if you're having problem with the Firebase console, [contact Firebase support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/).

Comment: Ok I understood and I received the email, but after the project is deleted it is counted with one less?

Comment: Yes. Once the project is deleted (after 30 days), it is really gone and won't count towards your limit anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much, clarified my doubts.